# Direct sum iff $S_a\cap S_b=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $X$ a $F$-linearly space. Let $S_1,...,S_n\subseteq X$ be subspaces of $X$. Decide, whether the following statements are true or false and give a proof or counterexample.

a)If $\sum_{k=1}^n S_k$ is a direct sum, then $S_j\cap S_k={0}$ for all $j,k\in \{1,...,n\}$ with $j\neq k$ holds.

b)If $S_j\cap S_k={0}$ for all $j,k\in \{1,...,n\}$ with $j\neq k$ holds, then $\sum_{k=1}^n S_k$ is a direct sum.

My thoughts so far for a) :
If **every** $x\in S_{1,...,n}$ is per definition(the def of direct sums) uniquely admitted, then $S_j$ and $S_k$ share nothing except the $0$-Vector(because thats in all Vectorspaces).
Therefore $S_j\cap S_k$ has to be $\{0\}$.

Is this right?
And how do I tackle the other direction?

Comment: This all comes back to understanding the definition of a "direct sum" you're right about a). I think b) is true, unless your textbook is being tricky with wording. With what words does your textbook define the phrase "this sum is a direct sum"?

Comment: Assume a basis. Convert the problem to one about row spaces of matrices.

Comment: Also, one of these two cases is of the insidious sort that resembles other true statements, but is easy to see false if you think about it a little.

Comment: For b) think of three distinct one-dimensional subspaces of a two-dimensional space

Comment: I thought of 2 plains that are orthogonal to each other, their intersection is clearly 0. Does this count? (obv in R^3 for example pruposes)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for a) appears to be correct

For b) the answer is no here is a counter example: Consider $X= \Bbb R^2 $ let $S_1= (x,x) $ and $S_2 = (y,0)$ and $S_3 = ( 0,z ) $ where $x,y,z \in \Bbb R $

Clearly any pair of them has trivial intersection but i think its clear that $S_2 \oplus S_3= \Bbb R^2$ so there no way that the sum of all three of them together can possibly be direct as $S_1 \cap (S_2 \oplus S_3) = S_1 $ so the only way this is going to be direct is if $ S_1 = (0,0) $ which clearly it is not.

In fact the right thing to ask for is that $ (S_1 + S_2 + \cdots + S_k) \cap S_{k+1} =0 $  for all k that you have if this is true then the sum is direct.